# How to named slice of a two-dimensional array in python

Tags: python-3.x

```py
points = [ (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8) ]
points = np.array(points)
plt.plot(points[:,0],points[:,1],'ro')
```

how to named this slice（[:,0] and [:,1]） ?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking... `x = points[:,0]` and `plt.plot(x,...` ?

Comment: python named slice。